# python, unable to make executable from script when I use scipy

Tags: python, scipy, exe, py2exe, cx-freeze

I have a python application and I want to extract the executable. I have used py2exe with no problem in other scripts. But in this one I get errors that I think have to do with the fact that I import and use scipy.

My code runs fine in eclipse. Trying to make the procedure with scipy at first I got 3 dlls missing ("libmmd.dll","MSVCP90.dll","libifcoremd.dll"). At first I exluded these from setup.py and the .exe file was made but it did not run. After that I downloaded the dll files (also deleted the exclusion of setup.py) and added them in "C:\Python27\DLLs" and also "C:\Windows\System32" and "C:\Windows\SysWOW64" (I have 64 bit windows7). Again the exe is created in the folder dist, but trying to run it I get this:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/145/py2exe.png/

Then I tried to do it with cx_Freeze. Again the .exe file was created but I get this error:
http://img521.imageshack.us/img521/3843/cxfreeze.png

So I suppose it has nothing to do with py2exe or cx_Freeze, but with the fact that scipy needs some dependencies that for some reason work in eclipse, but not when I make the executable.

Has anybody faced this problem? Any ideas on what I should do? 
Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I did it with pyinstaller-2.0. It did not run at first. Then I added the DLLs to the folder, after that I added numpy and scipy to the folder and finally after an error message I added kdtree.py to the folder. I was thrilled to see that it runned! But then dissapointed again cause it runs ONLY in my pc (some useful .exe there)! I added the folder it to a dropbox folder, from where it runs in me with no problem but not for others. The error in other machines I tried is:

importError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: Are you sure those DLLs you downloaded are 64bit? If you have cygwin you can check that with the "file" command. Have you searched your system if you didn't have those DLLs somewhere already (before downloading)?

Comment: I think they are 64bit. I have downloaded cygwin but how to use file command (sorry new to this)? Let's say that I want to test  msvcp90.dll that it is on "C:\Python27\DLLs". Whatever I try it outputs "msvcp90.dll: ERROR: cannot open `msvcp90.dll' (No such file or directory)"

Comment: as for if I had this dlls, I did not have them in the folders I added them, but I found them in other folders (eg in visual studio for MSVCP90.dll). Thank you for that suggestion! but I added these versions to python folder (also in numpy folder) but it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting the DLL files directly next to your executable. Also my py2exe gives some information about possible binary files that you might need to distribute with your application:

```
*** binary dependencies ***
Your executable(s) also depend on these dlls which are not included,
you may or may not need to distribute them.

Make sure you have the license if you distribute any of them, and
make sure you don't distribute files belonging to the operating system.
//Snip list of paths to dlls
```

Comment: Thank you, I have seen the list that py2exe gives and added all those files to the "dist" folder where the executable is. Still no success:(